# Python Iterate 2D array __iter__

Tags: python, list, class, loops, 2d

I am trying to create a 2D Array class and want to make the matrix iterable. Does anyone know how to go about doing this? I am a new to classes in python and still getting the hang of things. Also, how would **str** be implemented in my main? If i just use print(customMatrix) will that go and use the **str** method?

Heres what I'm working on. I know some of it isn't correct :)

```
class Array2D():
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        self.matrix = [[None]*height for _ in range(width)]

    def width(self):
        return self._width

    def height(self):
        return self._height

    def set(self, row, col, element):
        self.matrix[row][col] = element

    def get(self, row, col):
        return self.matrix[row][col]

    def row(self, row_no):
        rowList = []
        for item in self.matrix[row_no][item]:
            rowList.append(item)

    def column(self, col_no):
        colList = []
        for item in self.matrix[item][col_no]:
            colList.append(item)

    def __str__(self):
        #for row in self.matrix:
            #print (row)
        return (str(self.matrix))

    def __iter__(self):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a `yield` keyword which is handy in this case, It can be thought of as a return statement which saves the previous state while returning anything ,so when you call the method it first yields `self.matrix[0][0]` on the second call to this method it would yield `self.matrix[0][1]` and so on..

```
class Array2D():
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        self.matrix = [[None]*height for _ in range(width)]

    def width(self):
        return self._width

    def height(self):
        return self._height

    def set(self, row, col, element):
        self.matrix[row][col] = element

    def get(self, row, col):
        return self.matrix[row][col]

    def row(self, row_no):
        rowList = []
        for item in self.matrix[row_no][item]:
            rowList.append(item)

    def column(self, col_no):
        colList = []
        for item in self.matrix[item][col_no]:
            colList.append(item)

    def __str__(self):
    return_str = ""
    for i in xrange(self._height):
        for j in xrange(self._width):
            return_str+=str(self.matrix[i][j])+"    " #4 space between each element
        return_str+="\n"
    return return_str

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in xrange(self._height):
            for j in xrange(self._width):
                yield self.matrix[i][j]
```

Comment: Im getting 'IndexError: list index out of range' whenever the __str__ method is called. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I fixed it

Comment: This is working on your system? I am getting that __str__ is returning a non-string type.

Comment: I always thought __str___ was supposed to return a string, not actually print something. I changed it to return str(self.matrix[i][j]) + "    " and now it just prints out the first "none". For some reason it is not looping through

Answer (score 1):

```
def __iter__(self):
    for x in xrange(self.width):
         for y in xrange(self.height):
            yield self.matrix[x][y]
```

Read up on generators and the yield keyword, they're fun to use!

Comment: awesome, did not know about yield. How can I iterate the 2D list to print a string containing each item? I want it to be formatted like a matrix (new line after each row)

Comment: implemented `__str__` in my answer you can checkout @ncerice

Comment: @ncerice Note: using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) method you can define `__iter__` simply as: `def __iter__(self): return chain.from_iterable(self.matrix)`. You should definitely look at that module, it has a lot of very useful functions to deal with iterables.